# How to rewrite nested subqueries so that hive can run them

Tags: hive, hiveql

```
select  
  cd_gender,
  cd_marital_status,
  cd_education_status,
  count(*) cnt1,
  cd_purchase_estimate,
  count(*) cnt2,
  cd_credit_rating,
  count(*) cnt3,
  cd_dep_count,
  count(*) cnt4,
  cd_dep_employed_count,
  count(*) cnt5,
  cd_dep_college_count,
  count(*) cnt6
 from
  customer c,customer_address ca,customer_demographics
 where
  c.c_current_addr_sk = ca.ca_address_sk and
  ca_county in ('Greer County','Boone County','Cumberland County','Tyler County','Marion County') and
  cd_demo_sk = c.c_current_cdemo_sk and 
  exists (select *
          from store_sales,date_dim
          where c.c_customer_sk = ss_customer_sk and
                ss_sold_date_sk = d_date_sk and
                d_year = 1999 and
                d_moy between 1 and 1+3) and
   (exists (select *
            from web_sales,date_dim
            where c.c_customer_sk = ws_bill_customer_sk and
                  ws_sold_date_sk = d_date_sk and
                  d_year = 1999 and
                  d_moy between 1 ANd 1+3) or 
    exists (select * 
            from catalog_sales,date_dim
            where c.c_customer_sk = cs_ship_customer_sk and
                  cs_sold_date_sk = d_date_sk and
                  d_year = 1999 and
                  d_moy between 1 and 1+3))
 group by cd_gender,
          cd_marital_status,
          cd_education_status,
          cd_purchase_estimate,
          cd_credit_rating,
          cd_dep_count,
          cd_dep_employed_count,
          cd_dep_college_count
 order by cd_gender,
          cd_marital_status,
          cd_education_status,
          cd_purchase_estimate,
          cd_credit_rating,
          cd_dep_count,
          cd_dep_employed_count,
          cd_dep_college_count
limit 100;
```

When i run this query on hive it returns this error

"FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10249]: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.calcite.CalciteSubquerySemanticException: Line 23:2 Unsupported SubQuery Expression '3': Only SubQuery expressions that are top level conjuncts are allowed
"

This error occurs due to the second exists statement which contains a nested subquery.
Any ideas on how can i rewrite this query so it can work on hive?

Answer (score 0):

You might try reordering the query to prevent having subqueries. The conditions are evaluated serially in SQL, so operator precedence shouldn't be a problem.

```
where
    exists (select *
            from web_sales,date_dim
            where c.c_customer_sk = ws_bill_customer_sk and
                  ws_sold_date_sk = d_date_sk and
                  d_year = 1999 and
                  d_moy between 1 ANd 1+3) or 
    exists (select * 
            from catalog_sales,date_dim
            where c.c_customer_sk = cs_ship_customer_sk and
                  cs_sold_date_sk = d_date_sk and
                  d_year = 1999 and
                  d_moy between 1 and 1+3) and
  c.c_current_addr_sk = ca.ca_address_sk and
  ca_county in ('Greer County','Boone County','Cumberland County','Tyler County','Marion County') and
  cd_demo_sk = c.c_current_cdemo_sk and 
  exists (select *
          from store_sales,date_dim
          where c.c_customer_sk = ss_customer_sk and
                ss_sold_date_sk = d_date_sk and
                d_year = 1999 and
                d_moy between 1 and 1+3)
```

Comment: First of all thank you for taking the time to respond to my querstion.
I reordered the query as you suggested but i keep getting this error:

 "FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10249]: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.calcite.CalciteSubquerySemanticException: Line 20:1 Unsupported SubQuery Expression '3': Only SubQuery expressions that are top level conjuncts are allowed"

Comment: Okay, then you might need to specify the column names explicitly instead of using 1 and 3